# Drag drop data between 2 advancedDataGrid and clone instance

Tags: apache-flex, drag-and-drop, advanceddatagrid, arraycollection

I have 2 advanceddatagrid with dataprovider based on an arraycollection of an instanciated actionscript class.

I want to copy and duplicate data from the datagrid1 to the datagrid2...
For duplicate data it works fine, no problems .... but when I want to copy, in fact I want to clone the object from the grid1 to the grid2 ...

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You want the dragMoveEnabled property. If the value is false, you can only copy an item to the drop target. For a copy, the item in the drag initiator is not affected by the drop. (See http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dragdrop_4.html)